# UIButton does not detect Touch Down right away

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I created UIButton through interface builder. That button has Touch Down event and Touch Up Inside event on it which triggers necessary code to be executed. Somehow the Touch Down IBAction linked to that button is not getting called right away I touch the button. I have to move my finger little bit before that action gets called. Did anyone face same kind of issue ?

Is it because I have two IBActions assigned to the same button ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that button inside a scroll view?

Comment: adding on to the previous question, is there any gesture recognizers on the buttons superviews that have delaytouchesdown=YES?

Comment: @JackWu: Just checked superview does have delays content touches selected in interface builder.

Comment: @erkanyildiz: UIButton is inside UIView and that UIView is inside UIScrollView.

Comment: Try setting delaysContentTouches to NO.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you linked your action to the wrong control event, specifically, it sounds like you linked the action to one of the `Touch Drag...` events.

Make sure that you hook your action to the button's `Touch Down` control event.

Comment: I did set it up to Touch Down control event. Added some more details to initial question.